# "No doubt he .." or "There is no doubt (that) he ..."; are both grammatical?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

> **No doubt he** will pass the examination.
>
> **There is no doubt (*that*) he** will pass the examination.

Is the first way, "No doubt he", grammatical?

The second, of course is grammatical! What's the difference in context / meaning, if any?

Answer (score -2):

Variant 1 is more informal but very usual during speaking. I would not use it in a *written* official communication (maybe I am overly-cautious).

Variant 2 is the most correct way to say the same thing.